# How to stop a build (not aborting it) through user input

Tags: jenkins

As the title says, how can a build in Jenkins be stopped without being aborted?

The context involves a build that calls a script on a node cyclically, meaning the job calls a script on the node, the node executes the script, it finishes, the build does not finish but waits a certain amount of time and calls again the script, and so on.

The user would have to be able to log into Jenkins, to go where the job page is, and to just click something there to say ‘stop’. This ‘stop’ would mean either:
-   stop now, meaning placing a file on the node that is supposed to signal the script running there that it needs to gracefully stop the execution and Jenkins to collect whatever results are available at that point
-   or stop after the node finishes executing its script entirely, right before the next waiting happens

In this case, the build would be marked as successful.

Comment: Why do you need such complex thing? What are you trying to do? can you say that?

Answer (score -1):

Be aware: *this is a hack*!

Create a file i.e. WaitForInput.txt in Workspace with "FALSE" value.
Now read this file every 5 secs until WaitForInput.txt FALSE changed with TRUE.

So in this way, your build step will wait until WaitForInput.txt file data change from FALSE to TRUE.

To continue your job, go to workspace and change FALSE to TRUE and then your Job will continue in next 5 secs.